# Having problems building my website due to react scripts errors

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, build, aws-amplify, react-scripts

```
2022-04-18T12:57:22.132Z [INFO]: # Cloning repository: git@github.com:Sam-Losh/Portfolio_2022.git
2022-04-18T12:57:22.588Z [INFO]: Cloning into 'Portfolio_2022'...
2022-04-18T12:57:32.694Z [INFO]: Updating files:  63% (26015/40734)
2022-04-18T12:57:32.697Z [INFO]: Updating files:  64% (26070/40734)
2022-04-18T12:57:32.711Z [INFO]: Updating files:  65% (26478/40734)
2022-04-18T12:57:32.728Z [INFO]: Updating files:  66% (26885/40734)
2022-04-18T12:57:32.745Z [INFO]: Updating files:  67% (27292/40734)
2022-04-18T12:57:32.758Z [INFO]: Updating files:  68% (27700/40734)
2022-04-18T12:57:32.769Z [INFO]: Updating files:  69% (28107/40734)
2022-04-18T12:57:32.779Z [INFO]: Updating files:  70% (28514/40734)
2022-04-18T12:57:32.794Z [INFO]: Updating files:  71% (28922/40734)
2022-04-18T12:57:32.807Z [INFO]: Updating files:  72% (29329/40734)
2022-04-18T12:57:32.822Z [INFO]: Updating files:  73% (29736/40734)
2022-04-18T12:57:32.830Z [INFO]: Updating files:  74% (30144/40734)
2022-04-18T12:57:32.842Z [INFO]: Updating files:  75% (30551/40734)
2022-04-18T12:57:32.857Z [INFO]: Updating files:  76% (30958/40734)
2022-04-18T12:57:32.867Z [INFO]: Updating files:  77% (31366/40734)
2022-04-18T12:57:32.885Z [INFO]: Updating files:  78% (31773/40734)
2022-04-18T12:57:32.897Z [INFO]: Updating files:  79% (32180/40734)
2022-04-18T12:57:32.911Z [INFO]: Updating files:  80% (32588/40734)
2022-04-18T12:57:32.926Z [INFO]: Updating files:  81% (32995/40734)
2022-04-18T12:57:32.944Z [INFO]: Updating files:  82% (33402/40734)
2022-04-18T12:57:32.972Z [INFO]: Updating files:  83% (33810/40734)
2022-04-18T12:57:32.982Z [INFO]: Updating files:  84% (34217/40734)
2022-04-18T12:57:32.995Z [INFO]: Updating files:  85% (34624/40734)
2022-04-18T12:57:33.038Z [INFO]: Updating files:  86% (35032/40734)
2022-04-18T12:57:33.051Z [INFO]: Updating files:  87% (35439/40734)
2022-04-18T12:57:33.079Z [INFO]: Updating files:  88% (35846/40734)
2022-04-18T12:57:33.101Z [INFO]: Updating files:  89% (36254/40734)
2022-04-18T12:57:33.318Z [INFO]: Updating files:  90% (36661/40734)
2022-04-18T12:57:33.329Z [INFO]: Updating files:  91% (37068/40734)
2022-04-18T12:57:33.340Z [INFO]: Updating files:  92% (37476/40734)
2022-04-18T12:57:33.352Z [INFO]: Updating files:  93% (37883/40734)
2022-04-18T12:57:33.364Z [INFO]: Updating files:  94% (38290/40734)
2022-04-18T12:57:33.383Z [INFO]: Updating files:  95% (38698/40734)
2022-04-18T12:57:33.399Z [INFO]: Updating files:  96% (39105/40734)
2022-04-18T12:57:33.410Z [INFO]: Updating files:  97% (39512/40734)
2022-04-18T12:57:33.424Z [INFO]: Updating files:  98% (39920/40734)
2022-04-18T12:57:33.437Z [INFO]: Updating files:  99% (40327/40734)
2022-04-18T12:57:33.466Z [INFO]: Updating files: 100% (40734/40734)
Updating files: 100% (40734/40734), done.
2022-04-18T12:57:33.517Z [INFO]: # Switching to commit: 38f8e7e6144bb318ee4fc937868150b28e3bd0ab
2022-04-18T12:57:33.957Z [INFO]: Note: switching to '38f8e7e6144bb318ee4fc937868150b28e3bd0ab'.
                                 You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
                                 changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
                                 state without impacting any branches by switching back to a branch.
                                 If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
                                 do so (now or later) by using -c with the switch command. Example:
                                 git switch -c <new-branch-name>
                                 Or undo this operation with:
                                 git switch -
                                 Turn off this advice by setting config variable advice.detachedHead to false
                                 HEAD is now at 38f8e7e6 Updates
2022-04-18T12:57:34.001Z [INFO]: Successfully cleaned up Git credentials
2022-04-18T12:57:34.002Z [INFO]: # Checking for Git submodules at: /codebuild/output/src252889266/src/Portfolio_2022/.gitmodules
2022-04-18T12:57:34.034Z [INFO]: # Retrieving environment cache...
2022-04-18T12:57:34.172Z [INFO]: # Retrieved environment cache
2022-04-18T12:57:34.172Z [INFO]: ---- Setting Up SSM Secrets ----
2022-04-18T12:57:34.172Z [INFO]: SSM params {"Path":"/amplify/d25todb8of2oec/master/","WithDecryption":true}
2022-04-18T12:57:34.209Z [WARNING]: !Failed to set up process.env.secrets
2022-04-18T12:57:34.209Z [INFO]: No live updates for this build run
2022-04-18T12:57:34.214Z [INFO]: # Retrieving cache...
2022-04-18T12:57:34.254Z [INFO]: # Extracting cache...
2022-04-18T12:57:34.262Z [INFO]: # Extraction completed
2022-04-18T12:58:02.540Z [INFO]: ## Starting Backend Build
                                 ## Checking for associated backend environment...
                                 ## No backend environment association found, continuing...
                                 ## Completed Backend Build
                                 ## Starting Frontend Build
2022-04-18T12:58:02.542Z [INFO]: # Starting phase: preBuild
                                 # Executing command: npm install
2022-04-18T12:58:09.278Z [WARNING]: npm WARN
2022-04-18T12:58:09.282Z [WARNING]: ajv-keywords@3.5.2 requires a peer of ajv@^6.9.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
2022-04-18T12:58:09.289Z [WARNING]: npm
2022-04-18T12:58:09.289Z [WARNING]: WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules/fsevents):
                                    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
2022-04-18T12:58:09.291Z [INFO]: audited 1407 packages in 5.503s
2022-04-18T12:58:09.726Z [INFO]: 174 packages are looking for funding
                                 run `npm fund` for details
2022-04-18T12:58:09.727Z [INFO]: found 2 vulnerabilities (1 moderate, 1 high)
                                 run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
2022-04-18T12:58:09.827Z [INFO]: # Completed phase: preBuild
                                 # Starting phase: build
                                 # Executing command: npm run build
2022-04-18T12:58:09.991Z [INFO]: > client@0.1.0 build /codebuild/output/src252889266/src/Portfolio_2022
                                 > react-scripts build
2022-04-18T12:58:09.996Z [WARNING]: sh: /codebuild/output/src252889266/src/Portfolio_2022/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts: Permission denied
2022-04-18T12:58:10.000Z [WARNING]: npm
2022-04-18T12:58:10.000Z [WARNING]: ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
                                    npm ERR! errno 126
2022-04-18T12:58:10.002Z [WARNING]: npm
2022-04-18T12:58:10.002Z [WARNING]: ERR! client@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
                                    npm ERR! Exit status 126
                                    npm ERR!
                                    npm ERR! Failed at the client@0.1.0 build script.
                                    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2022-04-18T12:58:10.040Z [WARNING]: 
2022-04-18T12:58:10.041Z [WARNING]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
                                    npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-04-18T12_58_10_003Z-debug.log
2022-04-18T12:58:10.041Z [HELP]: Outputting the npm debug log
                                 0 info it worked if it ends with ok
                                 1 verbose cli [
                                 1 verbose cli   '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.0/bin/node',
                                 1 verbose cli   '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.0/bin/npm',
                                 1 verbose cli   'run',
                                 1 verbose cli   'build'
                                 1 verbose cli ]
                                 2 info using npm@6.14.16
                                 3 info using node@v14.19.0
                                 4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
                                 5 info lifecycle client@0.1.0~prebuild: client@0.1.0
                                 6 info lifecycle client@0.1.0~build: client@0.1.0
                                 7 verbose lifecycle client@0.1.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
                                 8 verbose lifecycle client@0.1.0~build: PATH: /root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/codebuild/output/src252889266/src/Portfolio_2022/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.6/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.0/bin:/root/.local/bin:/root/.local/bin:/root/.local/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/root/.dotnet/tools
                                 9 verbose lifecycle client@0.1.0~build: CWD: /codebuild/output/src252889266/src/Portfolio_2022
                                 10 silly lifecycle client@0.1.0~build: Args: [ '-c', 'react-scripts build' ]
                                 11 silly lifecycle client@0.1.0~build: Returned: code: 126  signal: null
                                 12 info lifecycle client@0.1.0~build: Failed to exec build script
                                 13 verbose stack Error: client@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
                                 13 verbose stack Exit status 126
                                 13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
                                 13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:400:28)
                                 13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
                                 13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
                                 13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1058:16)
                                 13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:293:5)
                                 14 verbose pkgid client@0.1.0
                                 15 verbose cwd /codebuild/output/src252889266/src/Portfolio_2022
                                 16 verbose Linux 4.14.246-187.474.amzn2.x86_64
                                 17 verbose argv "/root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.0/bin/node" "/root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.0/bin/npm" "run" "build"
                                 18 verbose node v14.19.0
                                 19 verbose npm  v6.14.16
                                 20 error code ELIFECYCLE
                                 21 error errno 126
                                 22 error client@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
                                 22 error Exit status 126
                                 23 error Failed at the client@0.1.0 build script.
                                 23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
                                 24 verbose exit [ 126, true ]
2022-04-18T12:58:10.044Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
2022-04-18T12:58:10.044Z [ERROR]: !!! Non-Zero Exit Code detected
2022-04-18T12:58:10.044Z [INFO]: # Starting environment caching...
2022-04-18T12:58:10.044Z [INFO]: # Environment caching completed
Terminating logging...
```

Ok, so I've been trying to build my react website with AWS Amplify and I keep running into
the same react-scripts error 126. If I build it on my computer instead I receive react-scripts error 1. I've searched through the internet looking for a solution but I can't seem to find one that works. I must be missing something, if someone can take a look at the error log above and walk me through a solution, I will be very grateful.

Update: Deleted NodeModules and reinstalled, didn't work

Answer (score 0):

`version: 1 frontend: phases: preBuild: commands: - npm install - chmod +x ./node_modules/.bin/react-scripts build: commands: - npm run build artifacts: baseDirectory: build files: - '**/*' cache: paths: - node_modules/**/*`

So it turns out I need to add a command between npm install and npm run build. To anyone looking to this for an answer, chmod +x ./node_modules/.bin/react-scripts , is the command you want to run. Cheers!